# Languages for creating 3d / 2.5d enviroments

Tags: 3d, 2.5d

I want to pick up a language that will allow me to create 2d/3d game environments. I come from web development using PHP, JS, XML and ideally I want to be able to integrate with those languages. I want to deploy to the web and to PC / Mac.

I'm considering Java, Actionscript 3, or some variant of C.

I'm pretty good at picking new languages up so that isn't a consideration.

I have briefly tried Java and ActionScript 3 and the problem is that I'm having difficulty seeing what the strengths of each language are (that is without learning the entire language anyway).

So if a few people could champion their tool of choice, what strengths/weaknesses it offers for game development (feel free to include commercial advantages!), that would certainly help me, it may help others too.

Comment: What languages do you know? It's almost certainly going to be faster to use one of those. Anything reasonably powerful will be able to do 3D. Actionscript yes, but with some difficulty.

Comment: Also, what target is this for? The web? Consoles?

Comment: Hey. See the top of the question

Comment: what exactly do you mean by afterthoughts?

Comment: It occurred to me to add details about my background before I saw your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would firmly vote for [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). The environment is great, it is fast, it can deploy to all of those platforms (plus iOS I believe).

You can also reuse your JavaScript skills to script it (as well as C#, if you want).

In terms of 2.5D, you'll just want to fix the camera along an axis.

Comment: You know any decent Javascript libraries that target gaming requirements?

Comment: Uh, you won't need a Javascript library. Unity3D is written in C++ I believe, and uses Javascript for scripting. (as well as C# and Boo IIRC)

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your answer. Will edit again when I've looked at unity 3d.

Comment: OK some of those demos are seriously impressive: download!

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to deploy to the Web and to make it multiplatform there is no better choice than X3D (formerly VRML), see [Web3D](http://www.web3d.org/). 
It is ISO for Web3D graphics, all mayor 3D tools have export for that format and being an international standard longevity is guaranteed and, what is most important, it is royalty free. Even WebGL will be supported. Internal scripting is subset of JavaScript and there is EAI for virtually any programming language but most of code online is Java and C++. Leading X3D engine, [Bitmanagement](http://www.bitmanagement.com/) Contact3D is on line with latest game engines (multitexturing, shaders, nurbs etc.) can be used as standalone app or as a plugin for all mayor web browsers.